# Как ускорить позиционирование в удалённом flv файле при доступе через http?

Tags: http, видео, ffmpeg, streaming, flv

Пробовал использовать ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:00:00 -i http://example.com/videofile.flv -t 00:01:00 -vcodec copy -acodec copy file.flv
```

Тут я пропускаю первый час видео и качаю 61-ю минуту.

Но это занимает 20 минут, т.к. фактически происходит скачивание всего файла с сервера и локальное его разбиение.

Как можно ускорить сей процесс?

Answer (score 4):

Для желающих пропустить нудное введение - решение в самом конце.

У каждого из форматов есть свои опции, которыми можно играться. То, что вы хотите, называется seek, не всеми форматами и не во всех случаях оно поддерживается: к примеру, если ваш источник - это простой HTTP сервер, типа апача или nginx, а видеофайл - простой файл на диске, то возможность непоследовательной перемотки определяется форматом файла, а так же настройками сервера: может ли он отдавать файл с произвольного места (проверить просто: при помощи wget -c начать качать файл, прервать и попробовать снова - если закачака продолжится - значит поддерживается, если начнётся заново - значит нет), плюс возвращает ли сервер размер файла в заголовках (возвращает - вам повезло, не возвращает - нет).

Если, хотя бы одно из вышеозначенных условий не выполняется, то перемотка будет последовательной - т.е. будет читаться файл до нужной временной метки.

Кроме того, если сервер - стриминговый, а файл, на самом деле не файл, а каноническое имя стрима и стрим - Live - то никакой перемотки не будет. Если стрим VOD - наличие перемотки зависит от того, может-ли сервер для данного транспорта (http) или нет (тут верны выкладки для обычного сервера).

На этом вводное слово закончим. Перейдём к делу.

На входе у вас работает стек форматов (в терминологии FFmpeg): tcp -> http -> flv.

Формат flv не умеет перемотку по временим - перенаправляет её на слой ниже (на протокольную часть: к примеру, rtmp умеет обрабатывать такие запросы). Http протокол же перемотку по времени делать не может в силу того, что он на это не рассчитан, ровно как и обычный файловый "протокол" (при доступе к локальному файлу). Но (при соблюдении условий выше) реализация умеет делать перемотку побайтово. Собственно сама перемотка осуществляется, внутри, при помощи более высокоуровневой функции, которая сначала пытается сделать перемотку по времени (в случае формата flv и протокола http эта попытка фейлится), если не удалось - то перемотку при помощи индекса (по сути, индекс хранит определённые временные метки и соответствующее смещение). Если индекса нет (или по какой-то другой причине, не позволяющей его использовать) то используется последовательное чтение кадров, сравнение их PTS с заданным.

Так вот, в случае flv таблица индекса не поддерживается. Точнее на уровне FFmpeg она реализована и создаётся динамически для уже прочитанного контента, т.е. перемотку в ещё непрочитанные данные можно осуществить, в данной связке (http+flv, file+flv), только путём последовательного чтения. Прямая перемотка осуществима только в связке rtmp+flv при условии поддержки медиа-сервером (в данном случае это будет VOD стриминг, можете в качестве стримера для этого взять nginx-rtmp).

Резюмируя: не ту связку формата и протокола вы выбрали. Как минимум, попробуйте сменить формат на mkv (matroska).

**UPD**: отвечая-учись. На flv файл можно навесить мета-информацию при помощи flvtool2, эту мета-информацию умеет понимать ffmpeg:

```
flvtool2 -UP media-file.flv
```

За подробностями: http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2007/03/18/flvtool2-flash-video-flv-metadata-cue-point-injector-and-cutting-tool/

И ещё несколько утилит для добавления мета-информации подобного рода: https://superuser.com/questions/286074/avoid-ffmpeg-to-lose-the-flv-files-keyframes/287441#287441

Самому ffmpeg никаких дополнительных опций передавать не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Есть небольшой шанс, что сервер, с которого вы собираетесь скачивать, поддерживает [HTTP pseudo streaming](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430518-pseudo-streaming-in-flash), и тогда можно просто добавить к ссылке параметр `?start=60`. В вашем варианте примерно так:

```
ffmpeg -i http://example.com/videofile.flv?start=60 -t 00:01:00 -vcodec copy -acodec copy file.flv
```

Но сначала проверьте VLC плеером или в браузере, что на том конце вас правильно понимают с этим параметром и отдают сразу же 60-ю минуту.